# EntityTooSmall in CompleteMultipartUploadResponse

Tags: c#, file-upload, amazon-s3

using .NET SDK v.1.5.21.0

I'm trying to upload a large file (63Mb) and I'm following the example at:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LLuploadFileDotNet.html

But using a helper instead the hole code and using jQuery File Upload

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/basic-plus.html

what I have is:

```
string bucket = "mybucket";

long totalSize = long.Parse(context.Request.Headers["X-File-Size"]),
        maxChunkSize = long.Parse(context.Request.Headers["X-File-MaxChunkSize"]),
        uploadedBytes = long.Parse(context.Request.Headers["X-File-UloadedBytes"]),
        partNumber = uploadedBytes / maxChunkSize + 1,
        fileSize = partNumber * inputStream.Length;

bool lastPart = inputStream.Length < maxChunkSize;

// http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LLuploadFileDotNet.html
if (partNumber == 1) // initialize upload
{
    iView.Utilities.Amazon_S3.S3MultipartUpload.InitializePartToCloud(fileName, bucket);
}

try
{
    // upload part
    iView.Utilities.Amazon_S3.S3MultipartUpload.UploadPartToCloud(fs, fileName, bucket, (int)partNumber, uploadedBytes, maxChunkSize);

    if (lastPart)
        // wrap it up and go home
        iView.Utilities.Amazon_S3.S3MultipartUpload.CompletePartToCloud(fileName, bucket);

}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    // Huston, we have a problem!
    //Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred: {0}", exception.Message);
    iView.Utilities.Amazon_S3.S3MultipartUpload.AbortPartToCloud(fileName, bucket);
}
```

and

```
public static class S3MultipartUpload
{
    private static string accessKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSAccessKey"];
    private static string secretAccessKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSSecretKey"];
    private static AmazonS3 client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretAccessKey);
    public static InitiateMultipartUploadResponse initResponse;
    public static List<UploadPartResponse> uploadResponses;

    public static void InitializePartToCloud(string destinationFilename, string destinationBucket)
    {
        // 1. Initialize.
        uploadResponses = new List<UploadPartResponse>();

        InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initRequest =
            new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest()
            .WithBucketName(destinationBucket)
            .WithKey(destinationFilename.TrimStart('/'));

        initResponse = client.InitiateMultipartUpload(initRequest);
    }
    public static void UploadPartToCloud(Stream fileStream, string destinationFilename, string destinationBucket, int partNumber, long uploadedBytes, long maxChunkedBytes)
    {
        // 2. Upload Parts.
        UploadPartRequest request = new UploadPartRequest()
            .WithBucketName(destinationBucket)
            .WithKey(destinationFilename.TrimStart('/'))
            .WithUploadId(initResponse.UploadId)
            .WithPartNumber(partNumber)
            .WithPartSize(maxChunkedBytes)
            .WithFilePosition(uploadedBytes)
            .WithInputStream(fileStream) as UploadPartRequest;

        uploadResponses.Add(client.UploadPart(request));
    }
    public static void CompletePartToCloud(string destinationFilename, string destinationBucket)
    {
        // Step 3: complete.
        CompleteMultipartUploadRequest compRequest =
            new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest()
            .WithBucketName(destinationBucket)
            .WithKey(destinationFilename.TrimStart('/'))
            .WithUploadId(initResponse.UploadId)
            .WithPartETags(uploadResponses);

        CompleteMultipartUploadResponse completeUploadResponse =
            client.CompleteMultipartUpload(compRequest);
    }
    public static void AbortPartToCloud(string destinationFilename, string destinationBucket)
    {
        // abort.
        client.AbortMultipartUpload(new AbortMultipartUploadRequest()
                .WithBucketName(destinationBucket)
                .WithKey(destinationFilename.TrimStart('/'))
                .WithUploadId(initResponse.UploadId));
    }
}
```

my `maxChunckedSize` is 6Mb (6 * (1024*1024)) as I have read that the minimum is 5Mb...

why am I getting `"Your proposed upload is smaller than the minimum allowed size"` exception? What am I doing wrong?

The error is:

```
<Error>
  <Code>EntityTooSmall</Code>
  <Message>Your proposed upload is smaller than the minimum allowed size</Message>
  <ETag>d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e</ETag>
  <MinSizeAllowed>5242880</MinSizeAllowed>
  <ProposedSize>0</ProposedSize>
  <RequestId>C70E7A23C87CE5FC</RequestId>
  <HostId>pmhuMXdRBSaCDxsQTHzucV5eUNcDORvKY0L4ZLMRBz7Ch1DeMh7BtQ6mmfBCLPM2</HostId>
  <PartNumber>1</PartNumber>
</Error>
```

How can I get `ProposedSize` if I'm passing the stream and stream length?

Comment: remove the `as UploadPartRequest` in your `UploadPartToCloud` methode and where is your loop in the `try{}` because if i understand that correctly you need to loop through your parts

Comment: the loop occurs automatically as the first part of the code is a handler where an async call is sending file parts. I have everything working now, but if anyone know the answer, I'm willing to give it the bounty points, or I will write the correct answer after the bounty period is over.

Comment: if you got it just write the answer there is no need to hide it :)

Comment: as I said, I will write it when the bounty period is over. Unless I get a request marked as *Urgent* :D

Comment: i am having the same issue...can you post the answer??thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a **working solution** for the latest **Amazon SDK** (as today: **v.1.5.37.0**)

Amazon S3 Multipart Upload works like:

1. Initialize the request using `client.InitiateMultipartUpload(initRequest)`
2. Send chunks of the file (loop until the end) using `client.UploadPart(request)`
3. Complete the request using `client.CompleteMultipartUpload(compRequest)`
4. If anything goes wrong, remember to dispose the client and request, as well fire the abort command using `client.AbortMultipartUpload(abortMultipartUploadRequest)`

I keep the client in `Session` as we need this for each chunk upload as well, keep an hold of the `ETags` that are now used to complete the process.

---

You can see an example and simple way of doing this in [**Amazon Docs**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3_UploadPart.htm) itself, I ended up having a class to do everything, plus, I have integrated with the lovely [**jQuery File Upload**](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) plugin (Handler code below as well).

The `S3MultipartUpload` is as follow

```
public class S3MultipartUpload : IDisposable
{
    string accessKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("AWSAccessKey");
    string secretAccessKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("AWSSecretKey");

    AmazonS3 client;
    public string OriginalFilename { get; set; }
    public string DestinationFilename { get; set; }
    public string DestinationBucket { get; set; }

    public InitiateMultipartUploadResponse initResponse;
    public List<PartETag> uploadPartETags;
    public string UploadId { get; private set; }

    public S3MultipartUpload(string destinationFilename, string destinationBucket)
    {
        if (client == null)
        {
            System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null; // disable proxy to make upload quicker

            client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretAccessKey, new AmazonS3Config()
            {
                RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1,
                CommunicationProtocol = Protocol.HTTP
            });

            this.OriginalFilename = destinationFilename.TrimStart('/');
            this.DestinationFilename = string.Format("{0:yyyy}{0:MM}{0:dd}{0:HH}{0:mm}{0:ss}{0:fffff}_{1}", DateTime.UtcNow, this.OriginalFilename);
            this.DestinationBucket = destinationBucket;

            this.InitializePartToCloud();
        }
    }

    private void InitializePartToCloud()
    {
        // 1. Initialize.
        uploadPartETags = new List<PartETag>();

        InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest();
        initRequest.BucketName = this.DestinationBucket;
        initRequest.Key = this.DestinationFilename;

        // make it public
        initRequest.AddHeader("x-amz-acl", "public-read");

        initResponse = client.InitiateMultipartUpload(initRequest);
    }
    public void UploadPartToCloud(Stream fileStream, long uploadedBytes, long maxChunkedBytes)
    {
        int partNumber = uploadPartETags.Count() + 1; // current part

        // 2. Upload Parts.
        UploadPartRequest request = new UploadPartRequest();
        request.BucketName = this.DestinationBucket;
        request.Key = this.DestinationFilename;
        request.UploadId = initResponse.UploadId;
        request.PartNumber = partNumber;
        request.PartSize = fileStream.Length;
        //request.FilePosition = uploadedBytes // remove this line?
        request.InputStream = fileStream; // as UploadPartRequest;

        var up = client.UploadPart(request);
        uploadPartETags.Add(new PartETag() { ETag = up.ETag, PartNumber = partNumber });
    }
    public string CompletePartToCloud()
    {
        // Step 3: complete.
        CompleteMultipartUploadRequest compRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest();
        compRequest.BucketName = this.DestinationBucket;
        compRequest.Key = this.DestinationFilename;
        compRequest.UploadId = initResponse.UploadId;
        compRequest.PartETags = uploadPartETags;

        string r = "Something went badly wrong";

        using (CompleteMultipartUploadResponse completeUploadResponse = client.CompleteMultipartUpload(compRequest))
            r = completeUploadResponse.ResponseXml;

        return r;
    }
    public void AbortPartToCloud()
    {
        // abort.
        client.AbortMultipartUpload(new AbortMultipartUploadRequest()
        {
            BucketName = this.DestinationBucket,
            Key = this.DestinationFilename,
            UploadId = initResponse.UploadId
        });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (client != null) client.Dispose();
        if (initResponse != null) initResponse.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I use `DestinationFilename` as the destination file so I can avoid the same name, but I keep the `OriginalFilename` as I needed later.

Using  jQuery File Upload Plugin, all works inside a Generic Handler, and the process is something like this:

```
// Upload partial file
private void UploadPartialFile(string fileName, HttpContext context, List<FilesStatus> statuses)
{
    if (context.Request.Files.Count != 1)
        throw new HttpRequestValidationException("Attempt to upload chunked file containing more than one fragment per request");

    var inputStream = context.Request.Files[0].InputStream;
    string contentRange = context.Request.Headers["Content-Range"]; // "bytes 0-6291455/14130271"

    int fileSize = int.Parse(contentRange.Split('/')[1]);,
        maxChunkSize = int.Parse(context.Request.Headers["X-Max-Chunk-Size"]),
        uploadedBytes = int.Parse(contentRange.Replace("bytes ", "").Split('-')[0]);

    iView.Utilities.AWS.S3MultipartUpload s3Upload = null;

    try
    {

        // ######################################################################################
        // 1. Initialize Amazon S3 Client
        if (uploadedBytes == 0)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["s3-upload"] = new iView.Utilities.AWS.S3MultipartUpload(fileName, awsBucket);

            s3Upload = (iView.Utilities.AWS.S3MultipartUpload)HttpContext.Current.Session["s3-upload"];
            string msg = System.String.Format("Upload started: {0} ({1:N0}Mb)", s3Upload.DestinationFilename, (fileSize / 1024));
            this.Log(msg);
        }

        // cast current session object
        if (s3Upload == null)
            s3Upload = (iView.Utilities.AWS.S3MultipartUpload)HttpContext.Current.Session["s3-upload"];

        // ######################################################################################
        // 2. Send Chunks
        s3Upload.UploadPartToCloud(inputStream, uploadedBytes, maxChunkSize);

        // ######################################################################################
        // 3. Complete Upload
        if (uploadedBytes + maxChunkSize > fileSize)
        {
            string completeRequest = s3Upload.CompletePartToCloud();
            this.Log(completeRequest); // log S3 response

            s3Upload.Dispose(); // dispose all objects
            HttpContext.Current.Session["s3-upload"] = null; // we don't need this anymore
        }

    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
            while (ex.InnerException != null)
                ex = ex.InnerException;

        this.Log(string.Format("{0}\n\n{1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace)); // log error

        s3Upload.AbortPartToCloud(); // abort current upload
        s3Upload.Dispose(); // dispose all objects

        statuses.Add(new FilesStatus(ex.Message));
        return;
    }

    statuses.Add(new FilesStatus(s3Upload.DestinationFilename, fileSize, ""));
}
```

Keep in mind that to have a `Session` object inside a Generic Handler, you need to implement `IRequiresSessionState` so your handler will look like:

```
public class UploadHandlerSimple : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
```

Inside `fileupload.js` (under `_initXHRData`) I have added an extra header called `X-Max-Chunk-Size` so I can pass this to Amazon and calculate if it's the last part of the uploaded file.

---

Fell free to comment and make smart edits for everyone to use.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you didn't set the content-length of the part inside the UploadPartToCloud() function.